# How to align based on a starting point of a text in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm trying to align a long(long enough to exceed a line) text based on it's starting point.
Following is an example.

I tried the code

```
<span style="font-size: 110%;"><b>Definition 1.1</b></span>
<span style="margin-left:2.0em;"><i>Stack Exchange</i> is a network of question 
and answer websites on diverse topics in many different fields, each site 
covering a specific topic, where questions, answers, and users are subject to a
reputation award process. The sites are modeled after Stack Overflow, a forum for
computer programming questions that was the original site in this network. The
reputation system is designed to allow the sites to be self-moderating.
<i>-Wikipedia/Stack Exchange</i></span>
```

**Which gives** [image: http://i.imgur.com/Qaeb8Qr.png]

**But I want the result like !** [image: http://i.imgur.com/yvsc4Nk.png]

How do I do this?

Comment: use left and right floats, nothing is easier... ;)

Comment: @webeno Ahhhhh, I forgot about that as I'm a novice on HTML...

Comment: Just like @webeno mentioned `<span class="left">Definition 1.1</span><span class="right">Larget test</span>   .left{float:left;}.right{float:right;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="width:600px">
    <div style="font-size: 110%; float:left; width:200px"><b>Definition 1.1</b></div>
    <div style="float:right; width:400px"><i>Stack Exchange</i> is a network of question 
    and answer websites on diverse topics in many different fields, each site 
    covering a specific topic, where questions, answers, and users are subject to a
    reputation award process. The sites are modeled after Stack Overflow, a forum for
    computer programming questions that was the original site in this network. The
    reputation system is designed to allow the sites to be self-moderating.
    <i>-Wikipedia/Stack Exchange</i></div>
</div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u59NZ/